# Multiple Ordering in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

I have two columns in a table (say Permissioned_on_Ques1, Permissioned_on_Ques2) of date type. I want to sort the table on latest updated date of both the columns. It should pick 1st column if both dates are equal.

```
Permissioned_on_Ques1     Permissioned_on_Ques2

31 Mar 2022 04:17:33      31 Mar 2022 04:17:33
30 Mar 2022 06:25:09      25 Feb 2022 03:35:43
```

Comment: Show us some sample data sorted in the desired way.

Comment: When both dates are equal, it's doesn't matter if you sort on the first or second date: they are equal.

Comment: @FrankHeikens yeah, Agreed. But how do I sort on latest column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `greatest` function to find the larger of the two dates and use it in `order by`:

```
order by greatest(Permissioned_on_Ques1, Permissioned_on_Ques2) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT
    Permissioned_onQues1,
    Permissioned_onQues2
FROM
    yourTableName
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Permissioned_onQues1 = Permissioned_onQues2
    THEN Permissioned_onQues1
    ELSE Permissioned_onQues2
    END
DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. But it first sorts on column 1, then on column 2. It doesnt solve the issue mentioned above.

Comment: @AainaArora fixed. Is it working now?
Btw, "greatest" approach is the best solution for now probably.

Comment: yes, it worked with the greatest keyword. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If Permissioned_on_Ques1 and Permissioned_on_Ques2 are not-null columns:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM <table>
ORDER BY GREATEST ( Permissioned_on_Ques1
                  , Permissioned_on_Ques2
                  ) desc
```

And if columns can have null-values:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM <table>
ORDER BY CASE 
         WHEN Permissioned_on_Ques1 IS NOT NULL 
          and Permissioned_on_Ques2 IS NOT NULL
         THEN GREATEST
                     ( Permissioned_on_Ques1
                     , Permissioned_on_Ques2
                     )
         ELSE COALESCE
                   ( Permissioned_on_Ques1
                   , Permissioned_on_Ques2
                   )
              END desc
```